# p6spy makes Tomcat8 will no longer redeploy when in use

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8, p6spy

Cannot redeploy tomcat when I am using p6spy on top of my Postgres database driver.

It works great until redeploy. When I do a redeploy, I get this error:

```
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: com.p6spy.engine.logging:name=P6LogOptions
```

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get around that problem by disabling the JMX functionality in P6Spy.  You would do this by setting the following setting in spy.properties.

```
jmx=false
```

If you are not using a DataSource (meaning that you have a JDBC URL), then you can also set 'jmx=false' as a URL parameter on the JDBC URL as well.

BTW - This looks like a bug in P6Spy.  If you don't mind, please create an issue in the [P6Spy GitHub project](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy/issues).

References:

- [P6Spy configuration](http://p6spy.github.io/p6spy/2.0/configandusage.html)